# dynamic_cast to the same type does not check type of object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, type-safety, dynamic-cast

I am trying to determine whether an object pointed by a T* pointer is truly a T object, or some other, unrelated type. I tried dynamic_cast, however it is less than useless, it returns the pointer itself instead of null even when it is obvious it does not point to a valid T object:

```
Object* garbage = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(0x12345678);
if( dynamic_cast<Object*>(garbage) == NULL ){
    cout << "Expected behaviour (by me)" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "You've got to be kidding me" << endl;
}
```

Is there any workaround for this, or some other solution? I've tried casting to void* and char* before the dynamic_cast to no avail, typeid is not enough either since I want to accept subclasses as well.

Some context: I'm writing a custom Array class implementing shallow conversion between different kinds of Arrays, like `Array<Object*>` and `Array<String*>`, and I would like to guarantee a minimal type safety by doing a dynamic type check at every element access, for example:

```
#define DEBUG
Array<String*> v(10);
Array<Object*> o = v;
o[0] = new Integer(1);      //  this is technically illegal but no idea how to check
//Array<String*> w = o;     //  this fails with an exception
String* str = v[0];         //  but this should fail horribly as well
cout << str << endl;
```

Casting to Object*, then doing the type check on the Object* works in a lot of cases, but it fails in the case of `Array<Object*>`, though I am not sure whether it is possible to insert something non-Object into an `Array<Object*>` without the use of reinterpret_cast.

Comment: What are `String` `Object` and `Integer`?  Why would your `String* str = v[0];` line fail?  `v[0]` is a `String*`, so that copy is perfectly valid.

Comment: I've put some clarification into the code. Object is the (public, non-virtual) base of String and Integer, all of them are polymorphic with at least a virtual destructor. Object derives privately from NonCopyable; String and Integer derives publicly and virtually from some "interfaces", but I doubt this comes into play.
I was implementing T* Array<T*>::operator [] to include the necessary type checks to ensure that it returns a valid object (or null) when I encountered the strange behaviour of dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your example, it sounds like you've got shallow copy Arrays which someone could trick into containing different types than they are supposed to contain.  I think the "normal" solution to this problem would be to make that difficult for users to do (i.e. don't provide conversions between `Array<T>` and `Array<U>`).  But, if you're set in your ideas I think this will work:

```
template<typename Subclass>
class Array {
public:
    // ...
    Subclass *operator [] (size_t index) {
        assert( index < size_ );
        assert( dynamic_cast<Subclass*>(static_cast<Object*>(internal_[index])) != NULL );
        // ...
    }
    // ...
private:
    size_t size_;
    Subclass **internal_;
};
```

You can do some template meta-magic and a static assert to make sure that `Subclass` is really a Subclass of `Object` (exactly how is a completely different topic).  Once that is out of the way, casting down to an Object* and then back up to `Subclass` with a dynamic_cast should accomplish your goal.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Shallow copy Arrays with (optional) dynamically checked conversion and element access. Conversion is easy, we just have to define a template copy constructor besides the original with dynamic_cast checks (where it is guaranteed the two types aren't the same), the problem is with element access.
There are two approaches I could think of: One involving a proxy class return value for operator [] instead of T*&, which checks all reads and writes against the real type of the array, and which I believe is not possible.

Comment: The second approach involves the check inside the operator [] itself, which I had trouble with, and which does not prevent illegal writes, but recognizes the incorrect state if someone tries to access the illegal element. My final approach is essentially the same as yours. I was unsure about its correctness, but frankly, I can not think of any case that could circumvent it, other than reinterpret_cast.

Comment: How can this prevent assignment of a `new Integer` into an `Array<Object*>` that happens to have a `String*` at that index?  The test as written, `dynamic_cast<Subclass*>(static_cast<Object*>(internal_[index]))`, would only verify that the incoming Integer could be cast to `Object*`, not `String*`... no?

Comment: It doesn't prevent the insertion of invalid objects into the array. However it prevents their use in a template context that would make them invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I'm following your needs, and makes some suggestions along the way...

```
Array<String*> v(10);
```

Seems this is meant to give you an array with 10 `String*`s initialised to NULL/0.

```
Array<Object*> o = v;
```

Creates an array of `v.size()` / 10 `Object*`s, each copied from the `String*s` in `v`.

```
o[0] = new Integer(1); //  technically illegal but no idea how to check
```

If this is illegal, then you obvious want to prevent overwriting of `Object*`s where that changes the run-time type...

- you need to intercept the `operator=` to implement the before/after type comparison
- to intercept `operator=`, you need `o[0]` to return a type whose `operator=` you can specify

  - letting `o[0]` return an Object* will never work, as pointers aren't user-defined classes: you can't modify the `operator=` behaviour
  - you must have o[0] return a proxy object - here pretty much an iterator though the semantics and assignment type assertion is different from Standard container iterators

Which brings us to:

```
Array<String*> w = o;     //  this fails with an exception
```

I assume this is only failing because your `o[0] = new Integer()` above wasn't failing first, and that the exception is your deliberate test that the element types meet expectations: no problem here then if you use a proxy object as discussed to stop the Integer getting into the `Array<Object*>`.

```
String* str = v[0];     //  should fail horribly as well
```

Again, I'm guessing this should fail because your earlier `Integer` assignment didn't, and there's no new problem here.

```
cout << str << endl;
```

So, the proxy object seems key.  Let me know if you don't know how to write one, but I'm guessing you do....

Comment: Yup, your assumptions are completely correct, other than the copy mechanism. I had a proxy idea, but dismissed it due to the difficulty of storing the initial type information; the approach I came up with was a type checking base class + subclass template with methods to check pointers against the original template parameter. The proxy would use this class to allow or disallow operations. The solution provided by SoapBox was easier to implement though. We do not check objects for validity until we access them as a certain type of pointer.

Comment: @Frigo: "do not check objects for validity until we access" - definitely a convenient simplification where acceptible :-). Re "correct, other than the copy mechanism", is that in response to my "each copied from the String*s in v"? Are you just meaning it did a deep copy / clone rather than a "plain" shallow copy (I didn't spell that out but it's what I was assuming), or is there something more to it? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A `dynamic_cast` from and to the same type is defined as a no-op in C++, so it cannot "fail" with your example. You can use the `typeid` operator instead.

For instance, this program is very likely to crash (which is the "expected" result for getting type information from an object at a random address):

```
int main()
{
    Object* garbage = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(0x12345678);
    if (typeid(*garbage) == typeid(Object))
        cout << "Your program thinks this garbage is an actual object!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There's still a chance of a false positive.

Comment: This will fail for subclasses of Object

Comment: @Ben Voigt, on the comparison of type_info or the crash?

Comment: @zneak: Calling `typeid` with an arbitrary pointer is undefined behavior, it could unexpectedly return `typeid(Object)`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, yeah, I hesitated writing _will_ crash, and it's the reason I put expected within quotes. Anyways, I suppose that OP doesn't plan on using lots of random pointers in his actual code.

Comment: It's the dereferencing part that crashes on my machine. When modifying it to determine the typeid of pointers instead: `typeid(garbage) == typeid(Object*)`, it does actually think that garbage is an object.

Comment: @Frigo, there's no RTTI associated to pointers. You cannot check the type of pointers at runtime, only the type of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just introduce a common base class with a virtual destructor.  With the empty-base optimization, this probably won't add any overhead, and it will make `dynamic_cast` just work.