# Strange results with object creation and binding

Tags: c++, this, dynamic-cast

Mistakenly I wrote something daft, which to my surprise worked.

```
class A
{    public:
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "You can't/won't see me !!!" << std::endl;
        }  
        A* get_me_the_current_object()
        {
            return this;
        }
};  
int main()
{
    A* abc = dynamic_cast<A*>(abc);
    abc->print();
}
```

Here, `A* abc = dynamic_cast<A*>(abc)`, I am doing dynamic_cast on a pointer, which isn't declared. But, it works, so I assumed that the above statement is broken as:

```
A* abc;
abc = dynamic_cast<A*>(abc);
```

and therefore, it works. However, on trying some more weird scenarios such as:

```
A* abc;
abc->print();
```

and, further

```
A* abc = abc->get_me_the_current_object(); 
abc->print();
```

I was flabbergasted, looking at how these examples worked and the mapping was done.
Can someone please elaborate on how these are working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Counter-question: Why would you do this?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If `print()` were virtual, then calling it would attempt to dereference `abc`, and *then* you'd crash, almost certainly.

Comment: @juanchopanza, the `dynamic_cast` isn't UB, dereferencing it to call the member functions is UB.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Agreed. I thought that much was clear.

Comment: Maybe to most people, but just clarifying for the OP

Comment: A related question [dynamic_cast to the same type does not check type of object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542135/dynamic-cast-to-the-same-type-does-not-check-type-of-object?rq=1)

Comment: @leemes: I'd never do such. Incidentally, I wrote something and later figured out that this didn't error out/crash.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I know it's UB to deref the member fns. I wanted to know how does it bind `abc` to the print() member fn, be it any hypothesis.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I was also surprised what exactly the `get_me_the_current_object()` fn. returns, what does `this` point to here.

Comment: It's undefined, but what's likely to happen with most compilers is that the `this` pointer has the same value as `abc` before the call, and so that's what's returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've made the common mistake of thinking that undefined behaviour and C++ bugs mean you should expect to see a dramatic crash or your computer catching fire. Sometimes nothing happens. That doesn't mean the code "works", because it's still got a bug, it's just that the symptoms haven't shown up ... **yet**.

> But, it works, so I assumed that the above statement is broken as:

Yes, all you're doing is converting an uninitialized pointer to the same type, i.e. no conversion needed, so the compiler does nothing.  Your pointer is still the same type and is still uninitialized.

This is similar to this:

```
int i = i;
```

This is valid according to the grammar of C++, because `i` is in scope at that point, but is undefined because it copies an uninitialized object. It's unlikely to actually set your computer on fire though, it appears to "work".

> Can someone please elaborate on how these are working?

Technically you're dereferencing an invalid pointer, which is undefined behaviour, but since your member functions don't actually use any members of the object, the invalid `this` pointer is not dereferenced, so the code "works" (or at least appears to.)

This is similar to:

```
void function(A* that)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
A* p;
function(p);
```

Because the `that` pointer is not used (like the `this` pointer is not used in your member functions) this doesn't necessarily crash, although it might do on implementations where even copying an uninitialized pointer could cause a hardware fault.  In your example it seems that your compiler doesn't need to dereference `abc` to call a non-static member function, and passing it as the hidden `this` parameter does not cause a hardware fault, but the behaviour is still undefined even though it doesn't fail in an obvious way such as a segfault..

Comment: Why null pointer? You first said it's uninitialized, not null.

Comment: You're claiming several things as valid which aren't: `int i = i;` is invalid (as it involves copying an uninitialized `int`), and in your last example, the call `function(p);` is also invalid (regardless of what `function` does), since it involves copying an uninitialized (invalid) pointer.  Both are undefined behavior.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: As you pointed out I made the common mistake of thinking that undefined behaviour and C++ bugs mean you should expect to see a dramatic crash.
Thanks pal for the beautiful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`abc` is uninitialized and points to an undefined location in memory, but your methods don't read anything from `*this` so they won't crash.

The fact that they won't crash is almost certainly implementation defined behavior though.

Comment: ... and thus undefined behavior and thus should be avoided.

Comment: It's not "implementation-defined", because that has a very specific meaning. If it was implementation-defined then implementations would be required to document whether they crash or not in this situation, but as this is undefined they can do anything.  You probably mean it varies from implementation to implementation, but it's never _defined_ to have a particular behaviour